# 'Series' object is not callable on a dataframe column with lists

Tags: python, list, function, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with many rows and columns.
One column - 'diagnostic superclass' has labels for every patient stored in rows as lists.
It looks like this:

```
['MI', 'HYP', 'STTC']
['MI', 'CD', 'STTC']
```

**I need to obtain a first label from every row**
**The desired output is a column which stores every first list element of every row**
so I wrote a function:

```
def labels(column_with_lists):
    label = column_with_lists
    for a in column_with_lists() :
        list_label = column_with_lists[0]
        label = list_label[0]
    return label
```

So when I run the code I face the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nikit/PycharmProjects/ECG/ECG.py", line 77, in <module>
    print(labels(y_true['diagnostic_superclass']))
  File "C:/Users/nikit/PycharmProjects/ECG/ECG.py", line 63, in labels
    for a in column_with_lists() :
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do with `column_with_lists()`? As the error says, that's a `Series`, which can't be called as a function.

Comment: Hello! I want to obtain the first value of every row list to create labels

Comment: Change `column_with_lists()` to `column_with_lists`

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan does not work

Comment: Please, share the **desired output**. That really helps readers trying to understand what you're achieving

Comment: @AlexandreB. updated

Comment: @Carcigenicate Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "C:/Users/nikit/PycharmProjects/ECG/ECG.py", line 77, in <module>
    print(labels(y_true['diagnostic_superclass']))
  File "C:/Users/nikit/PycharmProjects/ECG/ECG.py", line 64, in labels
    list_label = a[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Nike. Please, after taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you will have some rewards for that), please have a look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Then, edit the question adding a *sample* of your input data and the *desired output* on this sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of the `()` after the variable name, which means to to call it as a function. It's a pandas series, not a function.

One way to get a new series from the series of lists is with `pandas.Series.apply()`

```
def labels(column_with_lists):
    return column_with_lists.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to get a first element from every series?

Comment: That's what `x[0]` does

Answer (score 1):

As @Vivek Kalyanarangan said, remove the parenthesis and it will work but I think that you are confuse, why you are iterate in this part if you dont use "a" for anything?

```
for a in column_with_lists :
    list_label = column_with_lists[0]
    label = list_label[0]
```

I think that you must storage the first item of each row in a list. In fact, you don't need to use a function:

```
first_element_of_each_row = [i[0] for i in y_true['diagnostic_superclass'].to_numpy()]
```

This should be work.

Comment: I have tried but: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nikit/PycharmProjects/ECG/ECG.py", line 67, in <module>
    first_element_of_each_row = [i[0] for i in y_true['diagnostic_superclass'].to_numpy()]
  File "C:/Users/nikit/PycharmProjects/ECG/ECG.py", line 67, in <listcomp>
    first_element_of_each_row = [i[0] for i in y_true['diagnostic_superclass'].to_numpy()]
IndexError: list index out of range
`